# Memcached installed but class not found

Tags: php, memcached

If I run phpinfo() it tells me that [memcached](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) is installed.

```
memcached
memcached support   enabled
Version     1.0.2
libmemcached version    0.44
Session support     yes
igbinary support    no
```

I installed it with `sudo pecl install memcached`

But when I try to instantiate the memcached class it is not found:

$mc = new Memcached();

gets:

Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found

Never used PECL as an install mechanism before, do I need to do something extra in php.ini or somewhere to be able to use the class?

Comment: You say phpinfo() shows it so that's odd. I was going to ask if you included the module inside php.ini. Something like memcached.so or something.

Comment: Yep, extension = memcached.so is in php.ini

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's possible that it didn't install correctly or, as you say, you might need to add the following to php.ini:
`extension = memcached.so`

But since you say it shows up in phpinfo() it seems more likely that it just didn't install correctly. Were there any errors in the output during installation?

Also, to state the obvious, make sure you've restarted your server.

I wrote up a [tutorial on getting memcached running on Ubuntu](http://stevelove.org/2009/09/30/how-to-install-php-memcached-on-an-ubuntu-server/), which I mention not to self-promote, but just in case it's helpful.

Comment: Just checked out your very helpful blog post. Are you saying that the last version of libmemcached to work on Ubuntu 9.04 is 0.33 or can I go newer?

Comment: At the time of that post's original publication date a year ago, the highest version of libmemcached I could get working on Ubuntu 9.04 was 0.33. Newer versions may work, but you may just need to try them one at a time till you find one that does. Wish I could give you a better answer than that.

Comment: libmemcached-0.44 and "sudo pecl install memcached" worked fine on Ubuntu 9.04. No build errors.

Comment: Found my problem, rather embarrassing: I added extension=memcached.so to php.ini inside /etc/php5/apache but didn't update the one in /etc/php5/cli and I was running a test script from the cli. duh.

Comment: Your tutorial is great. Worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 12.10 with libmemcached-1.0.16. However I did need to install libcloog (`sudo apt-get install libcloog-ppl-dev`) to be able to run the `make` command.

Answer (score 1):

There is often a lot of confusion between 'Memcached' and 'Memcache'. It might be worth installing both to eliminate any such problems. You can use the following to install 'Memcache'

```
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
```

Comment: I've made this mistake before. Not realized the extension had a d while the ini lacked one

Comment: Yeah, that fork renaming has been the result of many moments of frustration and confusion I'm sure